# jQuery Working with Multiple Var Counters

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, var

I am using jQuery function to check the value of different inputs and depending if they have value, switch an associated image to an animated gif.

A counter is required, otherwise the animated gif keeps recycling.

```
// First Input and Image Swap
$("#input1").on('change keyup', function() {var counter=0;  
if ($('#input1').val()) {
if(counter=0){
$('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');counter++;
} } else { 
$('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');counter=0;
}
});

// Second Input and Image Swap
$("#input2").on('change keyup', function() {var counter=0;  
if ($('#input2').val()) {
if(counter=0){
$('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');counter++;
} } else { 
$('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');counter=0;
}
});
```

The code works on the first input, but the second input resets the counter to zero. Is there a way to specify specific var counters per function or can this be solved with loop?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Both of your counters are scoped to their containing functions, so there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Sorry @j08691 I failed to include the "if(counter=0){" from the original code.

Comment: you are using `=` which is an assignment operator to do the comparison that should have at least  `==`. the line `if(counter=0){` wont compare it ever infact assigning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a main problem:  *Assignment to variable*

**This line:**

```
// It's always assigning the value 0 (zero) to your local variable `counter`.
if (counter = 0)
```

**Run your code:**

*Some logs were added to illustrate*

```js
// First Input and Image Swap
$("#input1").on('change keyup', function() {
  var counter = 0;
  if ($('#input1').val()) {
    if (counter = 0) {
      $('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');
      counter++;
    }
  } else {
    $('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(`Counter 1 ${counter}`);
});

// Second Input and Image Swap
$("#input2").on('change keyup', function() {
  var counter = 0;
  if ($('#input2').val()) {
    if (counter = 0) {
      $('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');
      counter++;
    }
  } else {
    $('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(`Counter 2 ${counter}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Counter 1<br>
<input id='input1'>

<br> Counter 2<br>
<input id='input2'>
```

See, the local counters are always with `value = 0`.

**Second version of your code:**

*Using the correct logical operator `==`*

```
if (counter == 0)
```

**Run this version:**

```js
// First Input and Image Swap
$("#input1").on('change keyup', function() {
  var counter = 0;
  if ($('#input1').val()) {
    if (counter == 0) {
      $('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');
      counter++;
    }
  } else {
    $('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(`Counter 1 ${counter}`);
});

// Second Input and Image Swap
$("#input2").on('change keyup', function() {
  var counter = 0;
  if ($('#input2').val()) {
    if (counter == 0) {
      $('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');
      counter++;
    }
  } else {
    $('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(`Counter 2 ${counter}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Counter 1<br>
<input id='input1'>

<br> Counter 2<br>
<input id='input2'>
```

See, your variable counters were incremented.

**Third version, create a global variable**

```js
var counter = 0;
// First Input and Image Swap
$("#input1").on('change keyup', function() {
  if ($('#input1').val()) {
    if (counter == 0) {
      $('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');
      counter++;
    }
  } else {
    $('#image1').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(`Counter 1 ${counter}`);
});

// Second Input and Image Swap
$("#input2").on('change keyup', function() {
  if ($('#input2').val()) {
    if (counter == 0) {
      $('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.gif');
      counter++;
    }
  } else {
    $('#image2').prop('src', 'https://www.example.com/image.png');
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(`Counter 2 ${counter}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Counter 1<br>
<input id='input1'>

<br> Counter 2<br>
<input id='input2'>
```

This third version has the same behavior than the second version, however, only one counter variable is used.